# angular 10 'oidc-client' / IdentityServer4 .netCore 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1, angular10

I have issues calling api rest from client webSite angular 10, can't call request with Authorize attribute (get a 401 Unauthorized).

Environment :

```
- IdentityServer4 mvc .netCore 3.1
- Web.Api mvc .netCore 3.1
- client webapp, angular 10 with package 'oidc-client' (login/logout, ..., allowing to call api, ...)
```

web.api is configured like this (in ids):

```
  {
    "ClientId": "WebApi",
    "ClientSecret": "WebApi",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": "GrantTypes.CodeAndClientCredentials",
    "ClientType": "MvcApi",
    "RedirectUris": [
      "https://localhost:44372/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "https://localhost:44372/",
      "https://localhost:44372/signout-callback-oidc",
      "https://localhost:44372/home/index"
    ],
    "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://localhost:44372/account/frontchannellogout",
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "roles"
    ],
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true
  },
```

web app angular is configured like this in ids :

```
  {
    "ClientId": "ng.MOGUI.Web.UI",
    "ClientSecret": "ng.MOGUI.Web.UI",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": "GrantTypes.Implicit",
    "ClientType": "Mvc",
    "RedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
      "http://192.168.1.7:4200/auth-callback"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:4200/",
      "http://192.168.1.7:4200/"
    ],
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "WebAPI2",
      "WebApi",
      "api.read"
    ],
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true
  },
```

In angular these are the client settings :

```
export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
  return {
      authority: 'https://localhost:999',
      client_id: 'ng.MOGUI.Web.UI',
      client_secret: 'ng.MOGUI.Web.UI',
      response_mode : 'fragment',
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
      post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      response_type:"id_token token",
      // scope:"openid profile email",
      scope:"openid profile email",
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      loadUserInfo: true,
      automaticSilentRenew: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
```

oidc-client package is installed in the angular webapp, and works fine :

- login / logout **ok**
- call api request not securized with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] **ok**

but :

- call api request securized with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] **doesn't work and return 401 Unauthorized**.

oidc-client at login fills correctly user with necessary informations :

```
export class User {
  constructor(settings: UserSettings);

  id_token: string;
  session_state: any;
  access_token: string;
  refresh_token: string;
  token_type: string;
  scope: string;
  profile: ApplicationUser;
  expires_at: number;
  state: any;

  toStorageString(): string;

  readonly expires_in: number | undefined;
  readonly expired: boolean | undefined;
  readonly scopes: string[];
}
```

id_token and access_token seem to be ok

The call of the securized api request is done like this in angular :

```
  update(userRegistration: UpdateInputModel) {  
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': this.authorizationHeaderValue
      })
    };

    return this.http.post(this.configService.authApiURI + '/Account/Update', 
                          userRegistration, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

The acces_token seems to be correctly filled in **this.authorizationHeaderValue**

But if I replace it with an access_token (a little longer) got from an mvc client (to call the api) it works fine.

Have you any idea ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Web.api is missing in the client web app scope, this should be like this :

```
    export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
      return {
          authority: 'https://localhost:999',
          client_id: 'ng.MOGUI.Web.UI',
          client_secret: 'ng.MOGUI.Web.UI',
          response_mode : 'fragment',
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
          post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
          response_type:"id_token token",
          scope:"openid profile email **WebApi**",
      filterProtocolClaims: true,
      loadUserInfo: true,
      automaticSilentRenew: true,
      silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html'
  };
```

Sorry to bother you, it seemed to me that adding this scope made the application aborts, I suppose I was wrong ...

Regards.